# Student and correct answers probability

Tags: probability

Exam has 5 multiple choice questions, where each question has 4 options to choose from. Given that
you guessed all of them and got two correct answers, compute the the probability that the first question
was answered correctly.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @D.Khumoyun, would you like to accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. of ways of selecting any two questions which got correct answer is ${5\choose 2}$. This is the sample space of the event (say $A$).

$$\therefore n(S)={5\choose 2}$$

According to the given condition, one of the two  correct questions must be $Q.1$. So, $Q.1$ can be paired with four questions i.e $(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)$.

$$\therefore n(A)=4$$

$$\therefore P(A)=\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a question, the probability that it is answered correctly is $\frac{1}{4}$. Obviously the probability that it is answered incorrectly is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Let $A$ be the event that 2 questions are answered correctly. To find its probability, we need to find these two questions and answers them correctly and others incorrectly.
$$P(A)=\ ^5C_2 \times (\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{3}{4})^3$$

Now let $B$ be the event that the first question was answered correctly. Then $B \cap A$ means two questions were answered correctly and one of them was the first one. To find $P(B \cap A)$ we need to find the other question among the remaining four questions which was answered correctly. And then, we should  answer that question and the first question correctly, and the other 3 questions incorrectly.

$$P(B \cap A)=\ ^4C_1 \times (\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{3}{4})^3$$

Therefore the probability that the first question was answered correctly, given that exactly two questions were answered correctly is given by
$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{\ ^4C_1}{\ ^5C_2}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}$$